# How do you enter numbers on a Mac when making a cellular voice call with iPhone?

Tags: macos, call, continuity

I just upgraded to Yosemite, and sometimes perform outbound cellular calls from my Mac using my iPhone. However, if I call a company that has a phone menu I have to enter specific numbers to choose from those menu options.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Numbers can be entered using the keyboard. The correct tones will be produced and transmitted on your Yosemite Mac.

Comment: Just make sure that the FaceTime window is the active window. If another window has the focus, you'll type in that window...